# Replacing Column in Text FIle

Tags: python

I am trying to get the data in the third column and strip off the white spaces in between strings. I would like to then write it back to the third column. I am getting the desired results but then after the third column the formatting started to get out of whack.

code

```
import csv
import re
import pandas as pd

with open(r"sample.txt", "r") as infile, open(r"sample2.txt", "w") as outfile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile, delimiter="\t")
    writer = csv.writer(outfile, delimiter="\t")
    for row in reader:
        fmtd = row[2].split()
        fmtd = " ".join(fmtd)
        row[2] = fmtd
        writer.writerow(row)
```

row{2]

```
Chris     Dominguez
John White
Henry    Armstrong
```

row[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N0OJo.jpg) (after doing .split())

```
Chris Dominguez
John White
Henry Armstrong
```

final output I'm getting is (everything after row[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N0OJo.jpg) is not formatted under their respective columns):

```
Date      ID        Customer Name      House    Street     Apt     City    
1/1/21    1         Chris Dominguez        123   main st #54 miami
1/1/21    2         John Miller     545 johnson way homestead 
2/5/21    3         Henry Armstrong 365 arbol ct miami
```

final outcome I want(Data lined up under columns nicely how it was in the original file):

```
Date      ID        Customer Name      House    Street     Apt     City    
1/1/21    1         Chris Dominguez     123   main st      #54    miami
1/1/21    2         John Miller         545   johnson way         homestead 
2/5/21    3         Henry Armstrong     365   arbol ct            miami
```

[INPUT FILE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GiOpR.jpg)

[Output File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N0OJo.jpg)

Comment: Please post a sample of the full text file.

Comment: @RJAdriaansen I have added a link to the image in my original post.